# C# - "Login failed for user 'Username'(SQL Server 2014)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server 2014 using my C# code

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=IP\\SQLNameSERVER,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial Catalog=MyDB; User ID=Username; Password=password;"/>
</connectionStrings>

string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
     query = "SELECT * FROM [MyTable]";

     using (SqlCommand commandUserPortal = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
     {
         cn.Open();
     }
  }
```

but I get an error message:

> Login failed for user 'Username'.

When I use the same credentials to connect to DB through SQL Server Management Studio, it works fine without any issues.

The user has `db_datareader` permission.

I also tried

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=IP\\SQLNameSERVER,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial Catalog=MyDB; User ID=Username; Password=password;
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Did you try to login that username and password into SQL Server itself just for testing purpose?

Comment: Yes, i wrote this in my question

Comment: My bad got it.. is this a variable `ConnectionString` from here `new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))`

Comment: Yes, i update my question

Comment: Do you have any special characters in the password? You might need to [escape](https://www.connectionstrings.com/formating-rules-for-connection-strings/) them

Comment: hi, can you check the firewall? maybe it was blocking the port

Comment: @Martheen No. just numbers , Uppercase and lowercase letters

Comment: try to disable your firewall for testing or turn it off just to try.

Comment: @DrewAguirre I tried to do telnet to my server on port 1433 and it's success..

Comment: Alright.. hmmm....on the server properties connections items the "allow remote connection to this server" is checked ?

Comment: @DrewAguirre Yes, "allow remote connection to this server" is checked

Comment: can you try to remove the \\SQLNameSERVER.  Please try 
Data Source=IP,1433; 

sample :  Data Source=192.168.1.1,1433;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an accurate connection string via using `Add connection` from Visual studio.

**How:-**

Follow the next screen shots:-

1) View >> Server Explorer

[image]

2) Add Connection

[image]

3) Choose data source >> SQL Server

[image]

4) Type `Server Name`, `SQL Server authentication` , type `username` and `password`, and choose `database`.

[image]

5) Click `Test Connection` button.

[image]

6) The Connection that you created will be added here

[image]

7) Right click and choose `properties`

[image]

8) **Finally** copy and paste the connection string and use it , **and replace the stars (********) with your  password**

Comment: Work! Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change setting in sql server for you database. Allow both sql and windows authentication. For steps with images, check [here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/01/17/sql-server-fix-login-failed-for-user-username-the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-connection-microsoft-sql-server-error-18452/). I hope that you are not using windows authentication and also the DB server is reachable by your network. Everything else is looking ok to me.

Comment: I do it already and no i don't use with windows authentication

Comment: Try to open connection immediately after creating connection object. This is just a suggestion.

Comment: try removing "Network Library" element from connection string and please put screenshot or detail of exception.

Comment: Try to test connection in VS Server explorer with the details and parameter you have. Once DB connection is established. You can copy and paste connection string from there. Let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: Copy connection string from there and use in you code. Let me know if you problem is solved. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your Connection String:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data source=IP\SQLNameSERVER;Initial Catalog=DBname;User=Username;Password=Password; connection timeout=6000;" />
```

Also try to change your Code:

from:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
     query = "SELECT * FROM [MyTable]";

     using (SqlCommand commandUserPortal = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
     {
         cn.Open();
     }
  }
```

to:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
     query = "SELECT * FROM [MyTable]";
     cn.Open();
     using (SqlCommand commandUserPortal = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
     {

     }
  }
```

Comment: Did you check the SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Comment: What i need to check there?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following as Connection String

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=192.168.0.1; initial catalog=DBNAME;persist security info=True;user id=UserId;password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True ; Connect Timeout=10000" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Replace your Database name in the catalog,user id in user id and passeord in password

Comment: Did you check your user id,password ?? And also check the permission of your user id whether your user id have access to the database you want to log in

Comment: Yes i checked.. I success to connect with same credentials to DB through SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: could you please share a screen shot of the error ??